# Magento2: Pagination on listing page using static block

Tags: category, static-block, magento2.3.3, pagination

I have added a static block in the category
**Static block content:**
[image]
**Category :**
[image]
It shows all the products on a page. toolbar not showing:
[image]
[image]

How can I add the toolbar:
[image]

Comment: check with `F12` is causing anything?

Comment: what u want to say ? what is F12

Comment: Check with browser inspecting element with `F12` the toolbar style.

Comment: there is empty div of the toolbar.

Comment: Post your code. then we will look at it.

Comment: you can see my question m just usgin this "{{block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml"}}" in static block to get products , which have top and bottom content

Comment: Post your `list.phtml` code.

Comment: nothing to change. it's core Magento file list.phtml . you can check at your end create static block and use this code and see products showing without toolbar

Comment: Have you checked with the product list widget option?

Comment: yes, but I want to show this way. coz I have lot of data migrated from m1

Answer (score 1):

Check you have set a proper limit to show in sigle pagination

> Store >> Configuration >> Catalog >> Catalog >> StoreFront

[image]

> wrap layout in on container

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.toolbar" as="product_toolbar" template="Magento_Catalog::product/toolbar.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="category.product.type.details.renderers2" as="details.renderers">
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" as="default"/>
                </block>
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName">
                    <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">product_list_toolbar</argument>
                </action>
            </block>
```

- Call one phtml file in static block
- call toolbar by childhtml in newly created phtml file

Comment: yes, I have set a proper limit to show pagination.

Comment: apply my solution it will work

Answer (score 0):

I assumed that you have to add some content to category top and bottom of product list so you can create CMS static block and include in list.phtml file. It will fullfill your requirement.

Comment: every category have different static blocks, its shows the content top and bottom also shows products  but products pagination not showing ,as I ask in question .all products shows on one page

Answer (score 0):

First you check website inspect using your pagination part add z-index css style.
An element with greater stack order is always in front of an element with a lower stack order. after you can arrange css style using to proper view
Example:
z-index: -1;
or
z-index:initial;
or
z-index:auto;

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this, you would need to put a nested block in your admin static block, but this is not possible in CMS pages or admin static blocks.

In order to achieve this, you can try this:

Create a new layout file in your theme's `Magento_Catalog` folder.

> app/design/frontend/{vendor}/{theme}/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_cms.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct" name="category.products.list" as="product_list" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="Magento_Catalog::product/list/toolbar.phtml">
                    <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                </block>
                <action method="setToolbarBlockName">
                    <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">product_list_toolbar</argument>
                </action>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Note that this is copied from Magento's default category layout `catalog_category_view.xml`, so if your theme changes this, you might want to check your theme's layout file instead and make adjustments if necessary.

After that, you should be able to call this new layout in your admin static block like this:

`{{layout handle="catalog_cms"}}`

I haven't tested it, but it should output a product list with a pager on top.

Comment: first, let me check then let u know